# SQL Query to find out all managers and any manager that reports directly to that manager

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table demo_snap with columns of employee and supervisor information.
I want to find out all managers and any manager that reports directly to that manager including him/herself.
The query is really confusing me :(

The query which will give the employee and supervisor information is :

```
Select 
     employee_number,
     first_name e_first_name,
     last_name e_last_name,
     supervisor_employee_number,
     supervisor_first_name,
     supervisor_last_name
from demo
```

Can anybody help me out to mould this query in such a way to find all managers and any manager that reports directly to that manager including him/herself

Sample output of the above query is :

```
e_number f_name l_name supervisor_e_number s_first_name      s_last_name
   1      John  Smith     2                Adam                  juan
   4      Shree Lekha     2                Adam                  juan
   6      Hema  Malini    3                Shruti                Hasan
   7      Gauri Mikha     1                John                  Smith
```

The desired output i want that is i want to create a query such that the following employees are fetched :-

```
active managers- 2,3 and managers that reports to the active manager-1
```

The query I have created is :- but this is not giving the desied output

```
 WITH mgr_temp
      AS (SELECT person_id mgr_person_id,
                 employee_number mgr_num,
                 first_name mgr_name,
                 supervisor_number mgr_sup

           FROM demo mgr
          )
 SELECT mgrs.mgr_num HISL_ID,
        delegs.mgr_num DELEGATE_HISL_ID,
        mgrs.mgr_name emp_name,
        delegs.mgr_name sup_name
   FROM mgr_temp mgrs, mgr_temp delegs
  WHERE     mgrs.mgr_sup = delegs.mgr_sup
        AND mgrs.mgr_num <> delegs.mgr_num
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the result you expect to get? I, for one, wasn't able to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Putting together an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) would be helpful. Remember to change the database to Oracle 11.2.  Thanks!!

Comment: Please edit your question title. "All managers" already includes "managers that report to managers", so your requirement is effectively simply "all managers".

Comment: Why does only one of the managers (John Smith) have a record in the `demo_snap` table? Or perhaps the question should be "Why do some of the managers (Adam Juan, Shruti Hasan) **not** have a record in the `demo_snap` table?".  ???

Comment: Not Clear! Please re-word question and put some valid sample data!

Comment: please don't provide output of queries that aren't doing what you want, instead provide rows from the source tables. Then specify your "expected result". I can't unscramble an egg :)